# jQuery not triggering function on event

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-plugins, cordova

My jQuery function is not firing when called with an event.

If I put my function outside the event, though, everything works perfectly and there are no errors.

But, if I try to trigger it with an event, specifically submit or click, nothing happens and I don't get any errors.

I'm using Cordova, but when testing this on a test server on my computer, the same issues happen.

***My Cordova Doc***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Load jQuery-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Load My JS Plugins -->
    <script src="js/login.jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- jQuery Variables and other code used across the plugins-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

          function onDeviceReady()
          {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
          }

          function onSuccess(position)
          {
             //Trigger My Functions
             $("#login").submit(function()
             {
                 $(this).login();
             });
          }

          function onError(error)
          {
              alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
          }
    }
 });
     </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="deviceready">
      <div class="loginstuff">
          <form id="login">
              <h2>Login to your Account</h2>
              <label>Username</label>
              <input id="username"placeholder="Username" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" type='text'>
              <br>
              <label>Password</label>
              <input id="password" placeholder="********" type='password'>
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***NOTE - I know this plugin is simple, but I'm just using it for testing. Once I know it can be fired, I'll switch it back***

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        login: function()
        {
            alert("yes");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

***EDIT***

So I tested the function in a jsFiddle and everything worked perfectly. Basically, now I know my function works as is, but that the event is not firing. Wanted to let everyone know that.

Comment: Why are there two opening `{`s after `$(document).ready(function()`?

Comment: That was an error. used a code cleaner and thought I caught everything. Thanks

Comment: I recommend [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/) -- there's even a nice plugin for Sublime Text 2 (or 3). If fixing that error didn't help, try placing alerts in all callbacks and see what fires and what doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

Could the "deviceready" event be happening before your event handler is registered to listen to the event?  Maybe being inside the $(document).ready() callback is too late?

I don't like Cordova's [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html) because they have conflicting advice.  On one hand they tell you to wait from the DOM to be ready before adding the event listener but then they show an example with adding the listener in the HEAD before the DOM is loaded.

This approach is a bit long winded but if you have a race condition where deviceready is sometimes firing before $(document).ready() this might be a working solution.

You can try something like this in your HEAD tag:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var haveGeoLocation, isDomReady;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(position) {
  //Trigger My Functions
  haveGeoLocation = true;
  configLoginSubmit();
}

function onError(error) {
  alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// configLoginSubmit() will be called from both onSuccess and $(document).ready()
// but will not attempt it's business until both states are satisfied.
function configLoginSubmit() {
  if (isDomReady && haveGeoLocation) {
    $("#login").submit(function() {
      $(this).login();
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  isDomReady = true;
  configLoginSubmit();
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. If I'm using jQuery, doesn't `$(document).ready()` need to be the first thing called? The confusion comes from using Cordova where the `deviceready` has to be called first too. Basically, can you initialize jQuery a non jQuery function?